# How to implement WebRTC on android for app to app calling?

Tags: android, webrtc, simplewebrtc, apprtc

I am really new to WebRTC. What i need is to implement app to app voice calling (not video calling) feature in my android app. I want to call randomly among my app users by webRTC on android. I implemented appRTC sdk in android studio and made an app. By this app i can create or join in a room. And then i can create peer to peer connection (voice call). Its 1 to 1 calling in same room. But how to implement random calling. I just want to know the way i can achieve it. Thank you

Comment: Android developer documentation covers this. People aren't here to do your research for you. You can only get some help when you make an attempt yourself and post with a [mcve]

Comment: I dont want people do research for me. I want to know how can i do random calling by webRTC. I tried appRTC in android . But i cant implement random calling. I just wanna know some ways how i can do it.

Comment: If you still need this function, I think there is a detail for everything, you're looking for:[Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC), [Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC),

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing with webRTC quite a lot recently and created videochat-roullete as a sample for our webRTC wrapper, you might want to take a look into it : https://github.com/netguru/videochatguru-android

WebRTC can be problematic in many cases as it lacks of good documentation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use easyRTC which is built on webRTC. I have personally applied it in one of our project for audio /video and chat communication. Use this link https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/index.html
There is only one challenge I am facing right now, how to make it work on iOS

Comment: I need only android . Can you help me plz?.

Comment: Were you able to make it work on android and ios ? I'm creating a react native application I'm unable to find any package that enables me to connect with easyrtc client.

Comment: @Steve Link not opening